# Minecraft Aqua Affinity Enchantment

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What does the Aqua Affinity Enchantment do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Aqua Affinity](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting#Aqua_Affinity) allows the wearer of the enchanted helm to mine (break blocks) faster while underwater. Normally, being underwater slows down this action considerably. It also works while you're on ladders or otherwise suspended.

Answer (score -3):

It allows you to break blocks faster while you are underwater.

Answer (score -4):

Helps you mine faster underwater

Comment: This adds nothing that hasn't already been said, I'm afraid.